# Directive trouble - not capturing innerHTML text

Tags: css, angularjs

My end goal is to Capture a word and then display it in a special format.

Specifically I need to capture say a number `123.4567` and display it such that the last two digits appear in large format.

In order to address this, I started writing a directive. The first task was to capture the number in the directive.

However during my very first step, I am unable to capture the number. Instead of my directive catching the value `123.4567` , it is catching the variable `{{var1}}`

**plnkr here:** http://plnkr.co/edit/kenLYeZ4RVqR4fJMGL2x?p=info

```
app.directive('enlargeText',function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope,element,attributes){
      console.log(element['0'].innerHTML);  //should give me 123.4567 but does not

    }

  };
})
```

Any idea why this is happening and how I can fix it ?

Comment: You are using angular and still you require innerHTMl. Please use data binding.

Comment: The value is not parsed yet when the link function triggers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are a couple ways to do this, but you can split the number into two strings and display them inside a couple spans for the styling.

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/1z8VwEk2MenOkRKgWGff?p=preview

Directive:

```
app.directive('enlargeText', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      num: '='
    },
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<span class="smallDigit">{{small}}<span class="bigDigit">{{big}}</span></span>',
    link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
      scope.$watch('num', function(newVal) {
        if (!newVal) return;
        scope.small = scope.num.toString().slice(0, scope.num.toString().length - 2);
        scope.big = scope.num.toString().slice(-2);
      });
    }
  };
})
```

Usage:

```
 <enlarge-text num='var1'></enlarge-text>
 <enlarge-text num='var2'></enlarge-text>
```

Style (dependent on your situation):

```
.bigDigit {font-size:2em}
```

Note: This demo is assuming there will always be 2 or more digits after the decimal place.

Answer (score 0):

i changed your to apply custom styling on its contents

checkout this [PLUNKER LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mx7UctfBN2sd68uRpimo?p=preview)

the updated directive looks like

```
app.directive('enlargeText',function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div class="mystyle"> <div ng-transclude=""> </div>  </div>',
  };
})
```

**EDIT**

new plunker as per comments: [PLUNKER LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mqh3JQIVl9M4HSzPsEuc?p=preview)

you can pass whatever you wish using text parameter thru scope variable

Comment: how is this getting me contents of var1 in the directive ?

Comment: Can you kindly modify your plunker to demonstrate how I can capture var1 in the link function of the directive ?

Comment: check out the new link in EDIT reply